# SSIS Precedence Constraint Expression not working

Tags: ssis, constraints

I have an int variable `User::FileLineCount` scoped in a for loop container and in a task within the loop, I want to proceed from the task **depending in this variable's value**.

In the Precedence Constraint Editor I have chosen **Evaluation Operation** as **Expression** and the Expression as `@FileLineCount!=0`. There is another version to some other task as `@FileLineCount==0`. When I debug, I can see that the `User::FileLineCount` value is 0 but when I step Over the task I get `Unable to step. Not  Implemented.` error.

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**: Apparently the debugger could not step over so that was the reason for the error but the conditions still do not work properly.

**EDIT2**:[image: One constraint]

The other one is @FileLineCount==0. Doesnt work without OR'in as in the picture.

Comment: this is probably not related to the constraint. How do you know the constraint is not working?

Comment: The task has two options to move to depending on the value. But I get the error above when I try to step over the task.

Comment: What happens when you run it in normal mode, not in debug mode?

Comment: The error was from the debugger but the conditions do not fire properly still. It just loops through the tasks up to the point of the choice and restarts.

Comment: The awkward thing is, there are 2 options for something to happen; either its 0 or not. But even though both conditions exist, I just cant move to the next task on any other option. And I'm not in debug as well.

Comment: I think it has got something to do with the Logical AND and Logical OR constraint at the Precedence Constraint Editor. I'm not sure yet but I think both were being considered with an AND even though they are seperate. Hence the not doing anything part.

Comment: That only applies when you have more than one constraint to execute the task. Can you post images of the control flow and the constraint editor?

Comment: Very sorry..could not understand your question?What exactly you need to achieve?

Comment: what happens after determining @FileLineCount, do both tasks run? or none of them run?

Comment: well right now, correct ones run. As in if it's 0, the related task runs and the other one runs if not 0. I'm not sure why it does so or If I am doing the right thing. If I select AND instead of OR, like it was when I started the question, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had two paths leaving a data flow task one would go to a sql task and the other would go to another task.  I was struggling with this until I realized that two paths leaving the same data flow task would be an or if they were different paths.  I assume that you would use AND if you had multiple tasks going into one task and you needed them all to be true for it to proceed.  I'm not sure if this exactly what you are asking.

[image]

This would be or, because I want one or the other.

Where below I want all three to be true to continue to send the email.

[image]